# Row-Wise Pattern Replace with Replacement Value Coming from Another Column

Tags: r, string, replace, gsub

My data is like this:

```
Item | Process
ABC  | XYZ-ABC
AC   | XYZ-AC
AD   | XYZ-AD
AEM  | XYZ-AEM
AF   | XYZ-AF
AG   | WXY-AG
AHSG | WXY-AHSG
AI   | WXY-AI
AJ   | WXY-AJ
```

The `Process` column starts with a certain string, to which the value in the `Item` column is appended. Only the starting string should be retained. The values in the `Item` column and their lengths can vary. I want to do a row-wise `gsub()` where the pattern is the value in `Item`, the replacement is '' (blank) and the target is the `Process` column.

I cannot just strip everything after the "-" in `Process` because the delimiter can change. I don't care if the delimiter is left behind, as long as the rest gets removed. Also, the length of the starting string in `Process` can vary.

Here is what I've tried so far using `data.table`:

```
myData[grep(Item, Process), gsub(Item, "", Process)]
```

This works for the first row, but all remaining rows remain unchanged. I understand that this is because `gsub()` can take only a single pattern, and I'm providing multiple. I'm looking for a very efficient and quick way of achieving this. My data can have > 4 million rows. This is going to happen in a Shiny application, and I don't want to keep users waiting while this happens. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this in row-wise manner you can use `str_replace` from `stringr` which is vectorised over both `string` and `pattern`

```
stringr::str_replace(df$Process, df$Item, "")
#[1] "XYZ-" "XYZ-" "XYZ-" "XYZ-" "XYZ-" "WXY-" "WXY-" "WXY-" "WXY-"
```

Or `str_remove` which is an alias for `str_replace(string, pattern, "")`

```
stringr::str_remove(df$Process, df$Item)
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Item = c("ABC", "AC", "AD", "AEM", "AF", "AG", 
"AHSG", "AI", "AJ"), Process = c("XYZ-ABC", "XYZ-AC", "XYZ-AD", 
"XYZ-AEM", "XYZ-AF", "WXY-AG", "WXY-AHSG", "WXY-AI", "WXY-AJ"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```